# Android: dynamically add Item to menu in a navigationdrawer

Tags: android, xml, dynamic, menu, menuitem

I try to add dynamically Items to Item/Menu tree. My XML file look like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/r2_container"
    android:title="@string/myR2s">
    <menu>
        <!--
            Here I want some new Items...
        -->

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_addR2"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:title="@string/addR2ItemTitle" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="Settings">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/programm"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
            android:title="Programm" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

This menu is located in a navigationdrawer. I allready tried this code out:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
        present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start, menu);

    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Option1").setShortcut('3', 'c');
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Option2").setShortcut('3', 'c');
    menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Option3").setShortcut('4', 's');

    SubMenu sMenu = menu.addSubMenu(0, 3, 0, "SubMenu"); //If you want 
        to add submenu
    sMenu.add(0, 4, 0, "SubOption1").setShortcut('5', 'z');
    sMenu.add(0, 5, 0, "SubOption2").setShortcut('5', 'z');

    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately this code dosn't work. Nothing happens.

Do u have any idea to create dynamic items properly?

I am looking forward to you answers

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing your navigation drawer like provided in this link
[Material Design Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

or try using default navigation drawer template provided in Android Studio

Comment: I allready have the navigation drawer with the menu, but i can't add new item dynamically (in java).

Comment: that's why i am saying to implement it the way given in the link. It will allow you to add item dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You must take the item and the submenu. Then you can add a new item.

```
MenuItem item = navigationMenu.findItem(R.id.r2_container);
SubMenu subMenu = item.getSubMenu();

subMenu.add(R.id.r2_container, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, "Option1");
```